# Element a reserved Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I am making a javascript library where I make use of a wrapper around a HTML element (just like jQuery's `$()`). I wanted to call this simply `Element`, but later on I saw that javascript allready have an `Element` object: [Found here...](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_element.asp)

At this moment I use my wrapper as:

```
var divs = new Element('div').each(function (element) {
    console.log(new Element(element));
});
```

Remarkable is that when I log `Element` in the console (`console.log(Element);`), it outputs the following code (and my library is not included in the webpage):

[image: Logging Element]

And the above goes the same for `Node`.

Therefor my question: is `Element` a reserved word in javascript? Or is it perfectly fine to use it as a custom wrapper since it is a "fictive" object? And actually the same question for `Node`, since that is [is an object in javascript aswell](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_node.asp)?

Comment: `Element` isn't reserved, it's just a constructor that's already implemented natively.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So it is fine to use custom object like `Element` and `Node`? @AndrewLi

Comment: I would say no. They have native implementation and allow you to do basic functions. Every single element from the DOM is an Element object...

Comment: `Element` is a symbol exposed by the browser, like `window` and `alert`. It's not part of JavaScript, but it is part of the JavaScript environment. If you redefine it, things will not work very well.

Comment: @AndrewLi it's completely fine. Simply don't declare anything in the global namespace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) and [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) are parts of DOM.

It is perfectly fine to use `Element` or `Node` names for variables if they are used in non-global scope (block scopes, IIFEs, ES6/CommonJS modules) and don't overwrite global ones.

Globals can still be accessed on `window` if needed.

```
(() => {

class Element { ... }
class Node { ... }

Node !== window.Node;
document instanceof window.Node === true;

})();
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Modules, IIFEs, and blocks make use of the same lexical scoping rules that we know and love.

Comment: @estus, why then is everything still working when overwriting the global ones? Because that is not logic then.

Comment: @Galago It is likely that the browser maintains references to these constructors (they are not normal constructors because they are parts of DOM), so reassigning will possibly affect only third-party code that relies on something like `instanceof Node`. Anyway, it is not something that you should reassign, intentionally or not.